# problem with continuous

Tags: difference, tense, continuous

I can't understand why it's present continuous in this sentence:

> I never call my friends if I'm driving a car

Why we can't just say - if I drive a car? what's the difference?

Comment: You shouldn't make phone calls while you are in the act of driving. "I drive a car" could simply mean that you are a motorist, which isn't a reason to stop calling your friends!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It was helpful!